# Exclude duplicate row for which two variables are not nearest to one another

Tags: r, data.table

I have duplicate patient ID's for which the rows are identical expect for one variable (age). However, there is also an age check variable that illustrates which row is likely to be correct. The row for which the age is closest to the 'age check' is the row I would like to keep. So for id=3 the value 31 is closer to 30 than 28. Therefore, I would like to remove the row contaiing age_check== 28. I would like to use data.table in R.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,3,4,5)
age <- c(20,20,30,30,35,40)
age_check <- c(20,20,31,28,35,40)
dat <- data.table(id,age,age_check) #Create the data.table I used

   id age age_check
1:  1  20        20
2:  2  20        20
3:  3  30        31
4:  3  30        28
5:  4  35        35
6:  5  40        40

#ID 3 contains a duplicate for which I'd like to keep row 3
```

Output should be:

```
   id age age_check
1:  1  20        20
2:  2  20        20
3:  3  30        31
5:  4  35        35
6:  5  40        40
```

I have tried/started using the roll= functionality and the following code:

```
res <-  unique(dat[, .(id)])
res[, w := dat[c(.SD, age = age_check), on =.(id, age), roll= "nearest",   which=TRUE]]
```

This idea was already provided in an earlier post but not applied to values within one row.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be self-explanatory:

```
dat[, .SD[which.min(abs(age - age_check))], by = .(id, age)]
#   id age age_check
#1:  1  20        20
#2:  2  20        20
#3:  3  30        31
#4:  4  35        35
#5:  5  40        40
```

Comment: or using your own trick: `dat[dat[, .I[which.min(abs(age-age_check))], by=.(id)]$V1]`, which should be faster

Comment: Right, eventually the two will be of similar speed for this type of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to merge. You can just subtract `age` from `age_check` and keep the row with the minimum value. The `tidyverse` solution would be,

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
 mutate(new = abs(age - age_check)) %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 slice(which.min(new)) %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
> # Groups:   id [5]
>      id   age age_check
>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
> 1     1    20        20
> 2     2    20        20
> 3     3    30        31
> 4     4    35        35
> 5     5    40        40
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (provided that for all the non duplicated rows, the age_check is equal to the age):

```
dat[, min_dist := abs(age-age_check) == min(abs(age-age_check)), by = id]
dat <- dat[min_dist == T][, min_dist := NULL]

> dat
   id age age_check
1:  1  20        20
2:  2  20        20
3:  3  30        31
4:  4  35        35
5:  5  40        40
```

If the age check for non-duplicated rows is not always equal to age you could do:

```
dat[, dup_id := duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = T)] #find duplicates
dat[, min_dist := abs(age-age_check) == min(abs(age-age_check)), by = id]
dat <- dat[dup_id == F | min_dist == T][, c("dup_id", "min_dist") := NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`, if there won't be duplicate nearest values (as `filter()` returns all rows with the given value), you can use:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(abs(age-age_check) == min(abs(age-age_check)))

     id   age age_check
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1    1.   20.       20.
2    2.   20.       20.
3    3.   30.       31.
4    4.   35.       35.
5    5.   40.       40.
```

If there could be also duplicate nearest values, you can try:

```
dat %>%
 mutate(temp = abs(age-age_check)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 top_n(-1) %>%
 select(-temp)
```

Or if you prefer the base R:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$id, function(x) x[which.min(abs(x$age-x$age_check)), ]))

   id age age_check
1:  1  20        20
2:  2  20        20
3:  3  30        31
4:  4  35        35
5:  5  40        40
```